# Why can't I scroll in iOS 7.0 in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview, scroll, ios7

Regarding the setting the option of `delayContentTouches` on `UIScrollView` in iOS version 6.1 and lower,

1. If the setting is `YES`: The scroll function works properly, and *the touch event* occurred a little later.
2. If the setting is `NO`: The scroll function didn't work and *the touch event* occurred immediately

But in iOS 7.0, regardless of the setting the option of `delayContentTouches` (`YES` or `NO`),
the scroll function did not work well but *the touch event* occurred.

---

Download sampleCode

http://goo.gl/cSg1bE

Answer (score -1):

use this code in your `viewDidLoad()` method.

For Scrolling use this

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0];
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];


scrollToRowAtIndexPath:
```

is still avilable to ios 7.

```
float systemVersion= [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];

if(systemVersion >= 7.0f)
{
  self.edgesForExtendedLayout=UIRectEdgeNone;   
}
```